# What plant is this? How do I take care of it?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, palm

I recently came across this plant, can anyone tell me what is it called and how do I take care of it. Before I received it, it was placed in a very dimply lit room with no direct or indirect sunlight. On touching the leaf easily comes off.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be Dracaena Marginata. [Here](https://properlyrooted.com/dracaena-marginata/) is a pretty good web page describing care. Highlights from the article:

> Make sure container is well-drained. Use a potting soil with a loamy soil (a mixture of silt, sand, and clay), along with some peat. Like all Dracaenas, the marginata flourishes in a humid atmosphere. Mist the leaves occasionally, and keep the plant away from dry rooms with excessive central heating.
>
> Indoor Dracaena marginata plants thrive at a temperature of 60 to 70
> degrees. Place the plant behind a gauzy curtain or other location
> where it can get indirect sunlight. Bright sunshine scorches the
> leaves.

As for watering:

> Water every two weeks or three weeks in the winter. Keep soil slightly moist. Never drench or over- water. If you’re watering your plant too often, it results in yellow leaf tips or dark tips on pale young leaves. Canes may become mushy.